# How can I construct an array of static regexes in D?

Tags: d

I have several regular expressions that need to be applied in a row. For example:

```
import std.regex;

auto ctrex1 = ctRegex!(`def\s\n`);
auto ctrex2 = ctRegex!(`func\(`);
```

I'd like to wrap them in an array and use it as a function argument.

`StaticRegex!char[] staticRegexes = [ctrex1, ctrex2];`

It does not work however and the compiler throws

`Error: static variable ctrex1 cannot be read at compile time`

My naive understanding is that after compiler reads and compiles `ctrex1` and `ctrex2` there should not be a problem for it to compile an array for these objects later below. Assuming it just reads the statements from top to bottom. But it looks like my understanding is wrong. How does compiler work in this case and how do I construct an array of static regexes?

Comment: what's the context of that array assignment? if it is as module scope, the ctrex1 and 2 will have to be static as well.... i think.

Comment: yes, on module level. Got it to work after importing the module with regexes in the main and constructing the array there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an array of compile-time regular expression objects, because an array's values all must have the same type, but a compile-time regular expression has the expression string as a part of its type.

You could instead have a tuple of compile time regular expression objects, or add a level of indirection and wrap each into an uniform delegate, which then invokes the compile time regular expression object's matcher.